# Stuck at Laravel query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Trying to do a query in controller.

I have two tables in database:

```
students: id,name, surname,gender  
student_marks: id,student_id,year_id, subject_id, mark_id ...
```

> What I want is to count all the marks of students that their gender is
>   female or male.

```
 $girls = StudentMarks::where('student_id','=',Student::where('gender','female')->value('id'))->count();
```

But nothing shows up.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I would recommend that you first nail down the raw MySQL query.  Towards this end, you might want to give us some sample data from both tables, and the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to study on Laravel polymorphism. In your case, you need to make use of `belongsTo` and `hasMany` objects in this way.

In your `Student` model, add the following function

```
public function students_marks(){
  return $this->hasMany(StudentMark::class);
}
```

In your `StudentMark` model, add the following function

```
public function student(){
   return $this->belongsTo(Student::class, 'student_id', 'id');
}
```

While querying, use the `whereHas` clause to make your query as below

```
$student_marks = StudentMark::with('student')
->whereHas('student', function($student){
   $student->where('gender', 'female');
})->get()->count();
```

This should give you the count. For your own knowledge read more on `Laravel Eloquent EagerLoading`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your relations correct it would be something like this:

```
$girls = StudentMark::whereHas('student', function($q) {
    $q->where('gender', 'female');
})->count();
```

Where students is the relation function in studentMark. Every model should be singleton.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is go to `Student` model and define `protected $withCount=['studnet_marks']`

this will eagerload count of `student_marks` on `Student` model all the time.

So when you fetch a student you will have a `student_count` attribute that will contain count of `student_marks`.

Then your query should look something like :

```
 Student::whereHas('student_marks')->groupBy('gender')->get();
```

Basically get all the students that they have a `student_mark` and since we defined `withCount` in students model it will load a new attribute `student_mark_count` wich is count of student marks for each student.